# using scroll function to animate toggle an element

Tags: jquery, css, jsfiddle

I have a logo which on document ready is hidden with opacity of 0, then when the user scrolls to beyond 400px the logo animates into view and when it is less than 400px it animates out of view.

At the moment if you start the scroll it animates off then when you scroll beyond 400px it animate in. Is there a way I can have it not animate out at the moment of scroll.
http://jsfiddle.net/r1chyr1ch/DT32G/3/
Hope this makes sense.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.menuLogo').css('opacity', 0);
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $('.menuLogo').addClass('slideDown').removeClass('slideUp');
    } else {
        $('.menuLogo').removeClass('slideDown').addClass('slideUp');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsfiddle link isn't showing up, but I would suspect that `.menuLogo` either has opacity set to 1 or not set at all in your CSS. Both would show the logo until js kicks in and adds the additional class.

Comment: Hi @Duncan Beattie here is the link  [link to code regarding using scroll function to animate toggle an element](http://jsfiddle.net/r1chyr1ch/DT32G/3/)

Comment: As you can see the logo is there on load when it needs to be hidden from the start.

Comment: Setting `.menuLogo{opacity:0}` hides it when page loads, but when you scroll the first animation step kicks in which sets the opacity back to 1 so it can then fade it out. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pEqcb/1/) simplified, removed the keyframes and used basic transitions instead

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. @Duncan Beattie All is working well.